# A pointer-to-a-VLA-typed controlling expression in a _Generic expression

Tags: c, c11, variable-length-array

Why doesn't this static assertion trigger on major compilers?

```
void test(int x){
    _Static_assert(_Generic( (char(*)[x])0, 
    char (*)[1]: 1, default: 0),"");
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E67a79oPT

Are pointers to variable-length-arrays supposed to be compatible with pointers to fixed-length arrays?

Comment: Related: you can use the trick where pointers to array of incomplete type are compatible with any pointer to array of complete type (with the same type of elements). `#define IS_INT_ARRAY(x) _Generic((x), int(*)[]: 1, default: 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in fact compatible.

First, section 6.7.6.2p6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following about the compatibility of array types:

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible
> element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are
> integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the
> same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context
> which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the
> two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

From this, there is a requirement that if both array sizes are integer constant expressions (i.e. neither is a VLA) then they must be the same.  This however does not apply if one is a VLA, so that makes them compatible.

In addition, section 6.2.7p3 says the following regarding composite types:

> A composite type can be constructed from two types that are
> compatible; it is a type that is compatible with both of the two types
> and satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - If both types are array types, the following rules are applied:
>
>   - **If one type is an array of known constant size, the composite type is an array of that size.**
>   - Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array whose size is specified by an expression that is not evaluated, the behavior is
>     undefined.
>   - Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array whose size is specified, the composite type is a variable length array of that size.
>   - Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array of unspecified size, the composite type is a variable length array of unspecified
>     size.
>   - Otherwise, both types are arrays of unknown size and the composite type is an array of unknown size. The element type of the composite
>     type is the composite type of the two element types.

This means that when comparing the types `char(*)[x]` and `char(*)[1]`, their composite type is `char(*)[1]`.  What this also means is that `char(*)[x]` is compatible with *any* pointer to a fixed size array of `char`.  So if your function looked like this:

```
void test(int x){
    _Static_assert(_Generic( (char(*)[x])0, 
      char (*)[2]: 2, 
      char (*)[1]: 1, 
      default: 0),"");
}
```

You would get a compilation error because the controlling expression is compatible with multiple options, even though the options are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Composite types are used when combining two types, as when finding a common type for the result of a conditional expression (`E1 ? E2 : E3`) from its second and third operands or when merging two declarations of a function. The `_Generic` selection does not combine its operands or otherwise form a composite type, so composite types are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

They are compatible. C 2018 6.7.6.2 6 says “For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value…” Since it is not true that both size specifiers are integer constant expressions, the requirement to have the same value does not apply.

The pointer compatibility inherits from the pointed-to types.